# bxSlider and custom effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-effects, bxslider

I am using http://bxslider.com and I want to remove all effects. 
To be clear, I want effect like hide() and show() bewteen my images, just that. 
Is anything like this possbile to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Are You resolve problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try with speed param. From documentation:

```
speed
In ms, duration of time slide transitions will occupy
```

Try set it to `1ms` or `0ms`

Comment: Oh, but it is to fast I need the same time, just effect to change.

Comment: so try now with parameter `easing` set it to `def`

Comment: hm... got the error "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'def' of object #<Object> is not a function" whith parameter:  easing: 'def'..

Comment: Are You have this line in Your code: `<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` or similar, I mean include **easing lib**

Comment: Maybe it's stupid but trying easing: `"def" instead` of `easing: 'def'`?

Comment: It should work. I follow by this options on page: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/#example

Comment: $('#gallery').bxSlider({easing: 'def', 'auto':true, 'speed' : 1000, 'controls' : false}); like this to call?

Comment: Try it. Are You have any live example like jsFiddle?

Comment: no, I dont have, I still got the same error "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'def' of object #<Object> is not a function"

Comment: Are You must use this slider? Any other excepted?

Comment: any other solution wiil be helpfull

Comment: So You need only slider without any effect right? In left side picture, in right header with description right?

Comment: Well something like that, just images without any effects.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried passing in 'fade' to the mode option on constructor?

```
$("#slideshow").bxSlider({ mode:'fade' });
```

---

http://bxslider.com/options

I would try using the onBeforeSlide callback

```
function(currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject){
  // perform actions here
}
```

and call `.hide()` on both the `currentSlideHtmlObject` and the next slide in the sequence.

then you can use the `onAfterSlide` callback to .show() the next slide.

Comment: fade is effect and I want without any effects.

Comment: Oh so you are saying you don't want any effect transition, you want it to be a hard transition, but still occupy the same amount of time? SO if transition time is one second, to hide current slide, then one second later show next slide?

Comment: Ok it is acceptable but I dont how to do that. Some code please?

Comment: I think you have it backwards, you should hide the current + next slide before transition, and then show the new current slide after transition.